# MySQL gem on OSX 10.7 Lion

Tags: mysql, macos, rubygems

Did anyone got the MySQL gem 2.8.1. working on OSX 10.7 ?

I've installed MySQL 5.5.13 64bit and tried the following after the successful installation of MySQL:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -v='2.8.1' -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

When running a rake command - let's say rake db:migrate - I get this:

```
uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: i just installed my complete rails environment on snow leopard and then upgraded to lion. works perfectly

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had been struggling with this issue. The two above pointers worked. Here is what I did:

1. Added to .zshrc or your .bash_profile:

   `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"`
2. Executed this:

   `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" sudo gem install mysql -v='2.8.1' -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

Comment: After doing this: I did rake db:create and got the error: uninitialized constant Mysql

Comment: Did the trick!! Btw, if you're using bash you need to add the path to your .bash_profile instead of .zshrc

Comment: This worked for me: env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -v='2.8.1' -- --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-opt-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-opt-include=/usr/local/mysql/include --with-opt-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

Comment: Used this solution after upgrading from Snow Leopard to Lion. It works!

Comment: I'm always coming back to this post when installing MySQL gem on a fresh MacOS... so thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this to your ~/.bash_profile:

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to MySQL 5.1 is probably the easiest route, if possible.