# How can you install the mysql2 gem when MySQL was installed with homebrew on OS X Lion?

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, homebrew

I've been unable to install the mysql2 gem with MySQL installed via homebrew on OS X Lion.  I've tried a multitude of flags with the install, and I've still had no luck. Here are all the details.

*Software  Mac OS X Lion 10.7 (11A2063)*

`$ uname -a`

`Darwin Greenwood.local 11.0.1 Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.1: Wed Jun 29 19:53:22 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.23.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

`$ which gcc | xargs ls -l`

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Aug 18 14:09 /usr/bin/gcc -> llvm-gcc-4.2`

`$ brew info mysql`

`mysql 5.5.14`

`$ which mysql`

`/usr/local/bin/mysql`

`$ which mysql_config`

`/usr/local/bin/mysql_config`

`$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/mysql*`

`$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/libmysql*`

See output in this gist: https://gist.github.com/1158628

`$ sudo gem install mysql2`

See output in this gist: https://gist.github.com/1158612

`$ sudo find / -name mysql.h`

`/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.14/include/mysql.h`

`/usr/local/include/mysql.h`

`$ /usr/local/bin/mysql_config`

See output in this gist: https://gist.github.com/1158625

`$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config`

See output in this gist: https://gist.github.com/1158618

`$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local`

`$ sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config`

See output in this gist: https://gist.github.com/1158645

I also tried this answer:
[MySQL gem on OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340174/mysql-gem-on-osx-10-7-lion/6591223#6591223)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL with homebrew, and I was able to install the gem.