# Trouble with mysql gem on osx 10.6.8

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, rvm

I'm updating my database from sqlite to mySQL (@[mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short)...I know.  I know.  I should have done it at the beginning) and running into a problem.

Here's the process so far:

## Step 1:

update database.yml and run rake db:schema:load as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1670889/2128691)

```
rake aborted!
Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

## Step 2:

run `rvm @global do gem install mysql`

```
Fetching: mysql-2.9.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/charliekim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/charliekim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/charliekim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/charliekim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

## Step 3:

Search SO => [Can't install mysql gem on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299158/cant-install-mysql-gem-on-mac-os-x)

The solution in this answer didn't work as there is no `mySQL` directory in `/usr/local` so I can't edit the code there.

## Step 4:

output of `mkmf.log` => http://pastebin.com/7qSdv73R
output of `gcc -v` =>

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~6/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
```

## Edit 1:

I also ran: gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter

which returned:

```
Fetching: mysql-2.9.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql-2.9.1
Fetching: i18n-0.6.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.6.5
Fetching: atomic-1.1.13.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed atomic-1.1.13
Fetching: thread_safe-0.1.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.1.2
Fetching: activesupport-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.0.0
Fetching: activerecord-mysql-adapter-0.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-mysql-adapter-0.0.1
Fetching: builder-3.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.1.4
Fetching: activemodel-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activemodel-4.0.0
Fetching: arel-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed arel-4.0.0
Fetching: activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3
Parsing documentation for mysql-2.9.1
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/mysql/mysql_api.bundle, skipping
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.9.1
Parsing documentation for i18n-0.6.5
Installing ri documentation for i18n-0.6.5
Parsing documentation for atomic-1.1.13
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/atomic_reference.bundle, skipping
Installing ri documentation for atomic-1.1.13
Parsing documentation for thread_safe-0.1.2
Installing ri documentation for thread_safe-0.1.2
Parsing documentation for activesupport-4.0.0
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/active_support/values/unicode_tables.dat, skipping
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for activerecord-mysql-adapter-0.0.1
Installing ri documentation for activerecord-mysql-adapter-0.0.1
Parsing documentation for builder-3.1.4
/Users/charliekim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/parser.rb:87: warning: Unsupported encoding : ignored
/Users/charliekim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/parser.rb:87: warning: Unsupported encoding  ignored
Installing ri documentation for builder-3.1.4
Parsing documentation for activemodel-4.0.0
Installing ri documentation for activemodel-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for arel-4.0.0
Installing ri documentation for arel-4.0.0
Parsing documentation for activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3
Installing ri documentation for activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3
10 gems installed
```

but I still get the same error when running `rake db:schema:load`:

```
Rake aborted!
Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
...
```

## Edit 2:

Here is `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db/development
  pool: 5
  username: [name]
  password: [password]
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db/test
  pool: 5
  username: [name]
  password: [password]
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db/production
  pool: 5
  username: [name]
  password: [password]
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I added `gem "mysql"` to the `gemfile` and now am getting error

```
rake aborted!
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I don't know what those sockets should be, I filled them in based on a SO post, so that could be part of the problem.

Comment: do you have all necessary libraries installed for mysql like linux `libmysqlclient-dev`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340174/mysql-gem-on-osx-10-7-lion

Comment: searching for that took me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10855483/2128691) trying `brew install mysql` now

Comment: ooh you do not have mysql install in your system and trying to install gem.....

Comment: Can you please show your database.yml file

Comment: In your database.yml file, The adapter should be `mysql2` not `mysql`

Comment: i added `mysql2` gem to gemfile, ran `bundle install` and changed mysql > mysql2 in the db.yml file, still get the same error (can't connect through socket)

Comment: I have answered for `Please install the mysql adapter: gem install activerecord-mysql-adapte (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)` . I will try to help with socket error too..

Comment: if you add an answer i'll check it - socket error is a different issue and i'll have a crack at sorting it out myself first.  cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving Comment to answer.

**1.)** Answer for `Please install the mysql adapter: gem install activerecord-mysql-adapte (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)`

**ANS:** In your database.yml file, The adapter should be mysql2 not mysql

**2.)** `rake aborted!
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket /tmp/mysql.sock (2)`

**ANS:** Find your exact socket file using command

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

If you have password for root, do

```
mysqladmin -pxxxx variables | grep socket
```

You wil get the socket file using the above command and just replace it in your database.yml file

Cheers.!!