# heroku error while deploying app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, heroku-postgres

It's first time I'm trying to deploy on heroku. Short description of taken steps:

1. I use heroku gem(probably should be using heroku toolbelt)
2. In production I use postgres and thin server, in dev sqlite3 and webrick, in production I give url and in application.rb - config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
3. have an account on heroku, I do git push heroku master
4. heroku run rake db:setup, than heroku restart
5. when I heroku open it shows me 'An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.'

While uploading to heroku app doesn't show any error (just some warnings about deprecation). I have tried with another application and everything worked out, however with application I need something is wrong and can't even see where to look what is wrong. Maybe because of different gems I use, don't even know now.

Those lines below are highlighted in red while heroku logs:

```
2013-09-17T12:25:12.421144+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=nibeer.herokuapp.com fwd="78.63.251.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-17T12:25:35.921328+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=nibeer.herokuapp.com fwd="78.63.251.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-17T12:25:37.150365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=nibeer.herokuapp.com fwd="78.63.251.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-17T12:25:40.022882+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=nibeer.herokuapp.com fwd="78.63.251.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-17T12:25:43.650378+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=nibeer.herokuapp.com fwd="78.63.251.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-17T12:25:45.025048+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=nibeer.herokuapp.com fwd="78.63.251.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-17T12:25:48.171649+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=nibeer.herokuapp.com fwd="78.63.251.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Any suggestion on what is not good?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1046

Comment: @vitdes, can you show the full output of heroku logs?

Comment: @dax, I have made bundle update and this partially solved my problem. Now I'm not able to save any records on my app while on heroku, log shows no error and when check in console record exist. I found some clue that this might be due sqlite3 in dev and postgres in prod. So, I need to migrate to postgres in dev.and see what else heroku logs will show.

Comment: i would recommend changing over to mySQL entirely - if you have two databases you're going to have problems.  There's a lot about this on SO, here's the problems I ran into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399327/trouble-with-mysql-gem-on-osx-10-6-8

Comment: I was convinced that postgres is better!!!? Besides heroku runs on postgres.

Comment: okay, sorry, let me clarify - switch to one database for all environments if you can.

Comment: copy the full log... thats not the actual error